# Sum of Zero Nim-sum k-tuple Revisited

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Inspired by the previous [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784922/sum-of-zero-nim-sum-triplets), I'd like to ask whether there is a formula calculating $sum_{k}(n)=\sum_{\substack{0 \leq x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_k \leq n \\ x_1 \ xor \ \cdots \ xor \ x_k = 0}}(x_1 + \cdots + x_k)$ in $O(log(n))$.